# Hours at work rounded down

Tags: salary

If I work 38 1/3 hours a week at work and my employer only pays me for 38.3 hours, would you bother mentioning it?

I am payed minimum wage if that makes a difference?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146707/discussion-on-question-by-gabi23-hours-at-work-rounded-down); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> If I work 38 1/3 hours a week at work and my employer only pays me for 38.3 hours, would you bother mentioning it?

Honestly, no I wouldn't bother mentioning it. If we're being exact then yes they are technically underpaying you by 2 minutes a week, which over the full year is 104 minutes - or a little less than 2 hours. The problem with bringing this up is it's likely to be seen as petty - and pettiness (real or perceived) often begets pettiness in return, which in the long run could end up causing you more stress/hassle than those two minutes pay a week.

> Also my payslip does not include details such as hours worked or hourly rate - the total pay and tax and NI contributions.

This is a little baffling, my initial reaction is just what in the heck  *does* it show? A more considered response here is that it sounds as though they aren't in compliance with the law here. I'm assuming UK here (since you mention NI) and a payslip is [required to show](https://www.gov.uk/payslips) certain information:

- your earnings before and after any deductions
- the amount of any deductions that may change each time you’re paid, for example tax and National Insurance
- the number of hours you worked, if your pay varies depending on time worked

This may well not be malicious - Hanlon's Razor would point this to be simple ignorance/incompetence but I would absolutely follow up this matter. Payslips can be very important when it comes to such things as proof of earnings for loans and other financial matters as well as proof of tax and NI payments to HMRC, and it's far better to sort this out *before* you need them than get to finding out you need them urgently and have to chase retrospectively!

Comment: it shows total pay and my tax and NI contributions. It just doesn’t say my hours worked or my hourly rate.

Comment: @Gabi23 if you're paid hourly then the number of hours have to be included. The actual hourly rate doesn't have to be included IIRC

Comment: @motosubatsu is correct (for the UK at least). We had an issue at work last year because previously our payslips had been showing 1 hour worked at an hourly rate equal to [normal rate * hours worked] (I have no idea why! But it didn't affect my pay so I didn't make a fuss) and we got told off for it. Payslips now properly show hours worked * actual hourly rate

Comment: Good point about pettiness. If the OP complains about losing a few seconds of time per day, the company could ask "so, did you not stop working for even a few seconds? Hey, I saw you scratch your nose for 5 seconds, so we have to deduct that!"

Answer (score 35):

Every company has a policy regarding how partial hours are converted. But they also have to follow national and local policies.

I have worked for companies where the hours are recorded in the 1/4 hour or 15 minutes. I have worked for companies who allow you to declare the hours worked in 1/10 of an hour or 6 minute resolution.

Of course if there is an actual time clock that you punch in and out of they could calculate it down to the minute, with the understanding that if everybody arrives or leaves at the same time there is a expected inaccuracy.

Talk to your supervisor, payroll or HR for clarification. The first office I worked in had to explain that they only billed in 15 minute increments, and I didn't need to give the exact minute I arrived.  You want to ask so you don't enter your time wrong for years.

Comment: There is no clock in/out clock. I  just arrive and leave - I regularly have to stay 5-10 minutes late which isn’t recorded.

Comment: To add a bit here: The reason behind this minimum granularity often has to do with keeping any fractional part of the the per-unit payment as a non-repeating decimal value to avoid accounting errors (all sane work with money is done with decimals, not fractions, and the difference between 1/3 and 0.33 is not trivial). Anything that isn’t a multiple of 3 divided by 60 (which would need to be done for per-minute rates) gives a non-terminating decimal part, but any non-repeating decimal number divided by 4 or 10 will always give a non-repeating decimal part.

Answer (score 18):

What is your employer's accounting unit for time? That's their official definition of how things get rounded off. They have to round off somewhere; nobody even pretends to track work hours to extreme precision.

For example, when I was on time sheets/nonexempt, my employer used tenths of an hour, six minutes; anything shorter than that was discarded. This had the odd effect of officially giving us a 42 minute lunch break; management wanted to give us 45 but their accounting couldn't handle it so they called it 42 and politely ignored the fact that they might pay us for an extra 3 minutes a day.

Clock-watching is rarely a good long term strategy; the time spent trying to make your pay align precisely with hours worked cuts into actual productivity and since management evaluates you on the latter you wind up worse off rather than better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: +1 for the dangers of clock watching. How would OP feel about being tracked down to those 20 seconds every day?

Comment: @knallfrosch I regularly work 5-10 mins extra everyday unpaid.

Comment: Many of us do. It's less of an issue if you're being paid better, or are on salary rather than hourly anyway so the question is less fraught. But the answer is still that you need to take this up with management, find out what their accounting unit is, determine how they're rounding off, determine whether that's acceptable under your local laws, and then decide whether it's worth arguing about at the risk of their deciding they don't need you on staff at all.

Answer (score 6):

Your employer was accurate within two minutes (50 cents) for the entire week?? That's amazing.

Being this accurate, it sounds like management is wasting more time than it's worth on timeclock stuff. I hope it's all automated via badge and not manual tracking.

I wouldn't complain about it, per se, but it's always worthwhile to inquire about your employer's timeclock formula. Maybe they round off to the nearest 6 minute mark at the end of the week to attain `.1` accuracy? Aka, 6-minute rounding. I would hazard a guess and say that you will learn something new and not that your employer made a mistake.

I would let it go for a few paychecks and see if you can identify a trend or maybe experience a gross miscalculation. The more data you have, the better off you'll be in your discussion.

Answer (score 1):

> If I work 38 1/3 hours a week at work and my employer only pays me for 38.3 hours, would you bother mentioning it?

I would never bother raising this as a concern. If I only lose 2 minutes' worth of payment each week, which is 24 *seconds* daily, it's easily compensated by taking an extra sip from my coffee cup, or an extra blink somewhere.

If I were to bring this up, it'd take me at least a month or two's difference (8 or 16 minutes) to put together a reasonable email, and even more to collect evidences that the act of rounding down at this scale is causing substantial damage. Not to mention that it's physically and mentally more relaxing to just nap this time over than putting that into action. There are more approximations to happen around you in your life. This is probably not the hill you want to die on.